# How to save pictures having targetSdkVersion 30?

Tags: android, permissions, storage, android-permissions, mediastore

My app offers a feature that let the user to choose pictures from your local device and shown them.

My use case consists of selecting a picture from your gallery and save it in the directory `Pictures/Name Of My App`

Since now Android is obligating to target the 30 version of SDK before August 2021, and this SDK deprecates the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it will not be possible to read/save pictures in the "old way" using the `File` class. [As I understand in this article](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-11)

So I refactored the app to use `MediaStore API` and I removed `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` from the `AndroidManifest`. I also removed all the logic regarding the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission because I understood that for `MediaStore` is not needed anymore and I changed for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Which is (still) permitted to use.

After this change, it works fine in Android Q devices, I can read and write without any more permissions (and I don't actually know why because I am writing in a file in the external storage, but I guess it is because I am using `MediaStore`). But is not working with devices with android version lower than Android Q, even using `MediaStore` I receive `Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`.

At this point I don't understand anymore how I have to do to be able to save pictures in lower versions than Q because I see that I still need this permission.

My questions are:
This changes that I need to do regarding the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and the use of `MediaStore` are only affecting to the Android Q or above devices?

Should I leave the old logic (`File` class and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission) for versions lower than Android Q? If yes, `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` will still work for these versions?

If not, how can I save pictures using `MediaStore` without using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Here my code to save pictures:

```
fun savePictureInStorage(bitmap: Bitmap, name: String) {
        var fileOutputStream: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            val resolver = context.contentResolver
            val contentValues = ContentValues()
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/webp")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, path)
            }
            val imageUri =
                resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            fileOutputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(requireNotNull(imageUri))
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 80, fileOutputStream)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            try {
                fileOutputStream?.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `My app offers a feature that let the user to choose pictures from your local device and shown them.` Well ok. But why are you telling? As the rest of your post is about writing files. And you did not tell from where you got content to write to files. So can you adapt your post and tell that right away?

Comment: `How to save pictures having targetSdkVersion 30?` Well that depends on where you wanna save them to begin with. You did not mention that.

Comment: `and this SDK deprecates the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Never heard of that.

Comment: `it will not be possible to read/save pictures in the "old way" using the File class. ` You can save as many pictures as you want on an Android 10 device in the old way using File class in getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs(). And with android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to the whole external storage.

Comment: And on an Android 11 device you can use the File class in the old way to write picture files to public directories like DCIM and Pictures. No permissions needed.

Comment: My use case consists of selecting a picture from your gallery and save it in the directory `Pictures/Name Of My App` of the external storage.

Comment: I understand that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  will be deprecated because what I read here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-11

Comment: I do not read that there.

Comment: So you mean that while targeting 30, and writing into `Pictures` directory, if I am using a device with Android 11 I don't need any kind of permission, and for devices with Android 10 or below I can write asking for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"?

Comment: Exactly. Thats how i think it is. Just try for yourself.

Comment: blackapps is totally out of touch. (he posts a lot but never offers any solutions)  Android 30 ignores android:requestLegacyExternalStorage and in any case Google wants developers to remove android:requestLegacyExternalStorage from 5/5/21. @enoler, you are correct WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is no longer allowed either and needs to be removed too.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.

Comment: My solution was to change the way I was saving the pictures to use MediaStore for versions upper or equal to SDK 30, and change WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as much as I could. I don't know if at some point I will have problems in lower versions. But for the moment I am going to try this.